# CUDA cuBlasGetmatrix / cublasSetMatrix fails | Explanation of arguments

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu, cublas

I've attempted to copy the matrix `[1 2 3 4 ; 5 6 7 8 ; 9 10 11 12 ]` stored in column-major format as `x`, by first copying it to a matrix in an NVIDIA GPU `d_x` using `cublasSetMatrix`, and then copying `d_x` to `y` using `cublasGetMatrix()`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"cublas_v2.h"

int main()
{
    cublasHandle_t hand;
    float x[][3] = { {1,5,9} , {2,6,10} , {3,7,11} , {4,8,12} };
    float y[4][3] = {};
    float *d_x;

    printf("X\n");
    for( int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++ )
    {
        printf("Row %i:",i+1);
        for( int j = 0 ; j<3 ; j++ )
        {
            printf(" %f",x[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    printf("Y\n");
    for( int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++ )
    {
        printf("Row %i:",i+1);
        for( int j = 0 ; j<3 ; j++ )
        {
            printf(" %f",y[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    cublasCreate( &hand );
    cudaMalloc( &d_x,sizeof(d_x) );
    cublasSetMatrix( 3,4,sizeof(float),x,3,d_x,3 );
    cublasGetMatrix( 3,4,sizeof(float),d_x,3,y,3 );

    printf("X\n");
    for( int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++ )
    {
        printf("Row %i:",i+1);
        for( int j = 0 ; j<3 ; j++ )
        {
            printf(" %f",x[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    printf("Y\n");
    for( int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++ )
    {
        printf("Row %i:",i+1);
        for( int j = 0 ; j<3 ; j++ )
        {
            printf(" %f",y[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }


    cudaFree( d_x );
    cublasDestroy( hand );
    return 0;
}
```

The output after the copy shows `y` filled with `0`s.

Did any of the `cublas` function calls fail ?

Or/And

Have the wrong arguments been passed to the `cublas` functions ?

Also, please explain the purpose of each argument to the functions.

Using GeForce GTX 650 with CUDA 6.5 on Fedora 21 x86_64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only actual problem in your code is here:

```
cudaMalloc( &d_x,sizeof(d_x) );
```

`sizeof(d_x)` is just the size of a pointer.  You can fix it like this:

```
cudaMalloc( &d_x,sizeof(x) );
```

If you want to find out if a CUBLAS API call is failing, then you should check the return code of the API call:

```
cublasStatus_t res = cublasSetMatrix( 3,4,sizeof(float),x,3,d_x,3 );
```

Regarding a description of the parameters, you have them all correct (other than the allocation error associated with `d_x`).  So it's not clear which one you need a description of, but they are all described in the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublassetmatrix).

CUDA API calls (like `cudaMalloc`) also return an error code, so you should check those as well.  Any time you're having trouble with a CUDA code, it's a good idea to use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).  You can also run your codes with `cuda-memcheck` as a quick test.